# Problem to iterate through URLs with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to iterate through the pages of a site using Selenium library, but I can only get the home page.

I redid my code to try to fix this problem, however, I only get the following message: **InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id.**

The code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\MYPATH\chromedriver.exe')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')

title_list = []
date_list  = []
genre_list = []

for page_num in range(1, 11):
url = r"https://www.albumoftheyear.org/list/1500-rolling-stones-500-greatest-albums-of-all-time-2020/{}".format(page_num)
driver.get(url)

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "centerContent"))
    )
    albumlistrow = element.find_elements_by_class_name('albumListRow')
    for a in albumlistrow:
        title = a.find_element_by_class_name('albumListTitle')
        date = a.find_element_by_class_name('albumListDate')
        try:
            genre = a.find_element_by_class_name('albumListGenre')
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass
        title_list.append(title.text)
        date_list.append(date.text)
        genre_list.append(genre.text)

finally:
    driver.close()

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(title_list,date_list,genre_list)), columns=['title', 'data','genre'])
df.head()
```

Comment: Could you please correctly format the code so it can be properly assessed? Some iterations/loops are incorrectly indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your error, but since you said you have problem iterating over pages I tried to replicate that and found that they have bot pretection system by Cloudflare.

```
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
```

This seems to fix the problem.

Tested with code below

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
#ChromeDriverManager is for my local machine, you can use your exec_path
d = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)
d.implicitly_wait(5)

for page_num in range(1,11):
    url = r"https://www.albumoftheyear.org/list/1500-rolling-stones-500-greatest-albums-of-all-time-2020/{}".format(page_num)
    d.get(url)
    sleep(3)
```

Imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the error still occurs. The following messages appear during execution:
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53530/devtools/browser/28978fe2-d8a9-46ee-bc85-0aa28c426868
[7572:11412:0910/093029.798:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(981)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[13240:12308:0910/093032.997:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [09:30:32.997] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device connected to the system is not working. (0x1F)

Comment: @PSCM Code I posted works fine iterating through pages. If you only added my suggested fix on your code with .add_argument, try to create webdriver instance after creating options like I did in my code. This may cause your issues, because you're only declaring your chrome options, but you're not using them in an argument. So I think  `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\MYPATH\chromedriver.exe') ` should be below the part where you created options and you should add it as an argument  `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\MYPATH\chromedriver.exe', options= options) `

Comment: @PSCM i'm not sure if what i suggested above is mandatory tho. Never tested it, I always use it as an argument when creating webdriver.

Comment: thanks! I fixed the issue with your solution.